# Can I sort by a property in Rails after doing an :includes on the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a snippet of code: `User.includes(:cars, :books).find_by_id(params[:user_id])`

`Book` has an attribute `slot_number` that returns values 0-4. For some reason, I can get an array that isn't arranged 0-4, in that order.

Is there a way to ensure those `books` are sorted by `slot_number`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes:

1. There's no benefit to eager loading (`includes`) here since you're loading a single record. Eager loading is useful when you're loading a collection and referencing associations for each of the loaded instances, like `cars = Car.includes(:manufacturer).where(year: 1990..2001)`.
2. Sorting an eager-loaded collection only makes sense in the context of the parent object, or otherwise loading the collection outside of the context of the parent collection (i.e., not eager). For example, you could do this:

   ```
   readers = Reader.includes(:books).order('books.title').where(state: 'TX')
   readers.each do |reader|
     puts reader.name + " likes " + books.collect(&:title).to_sentence
   end
   ```

   But this requires that the collection is sorted for each `Reader`. The appropriate place for this declaration is on the association:

   ```
   class Reader < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :books, -> { order(:title) }
   end
   ```

   Otherwise  you really just want to load a separate collection:

   ```
   cars = Car.where(year: 1990..2001)
   manufacturers = Manufacturer.where(cars: cars).order(:name)
   ```
3. If you *are* only loading associations for a single record, you should be applying the scope to the relationship and *not* eager loading it:

   ```
   @user = User.find(1)
   @books = @user.books.order(:slot_number)
   @cars = @user.cars.order(:year)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort the associated records. Try this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, -> { order(slot_number: :asc) }
end
```

Or when this is not the default sorting that you want to have applied all the time:

```
user = User.includes(:cars, :books).find_by_id(params[:user_id])
user.books.order(slot_number: :asc)
```

But: since you are selecting the `User` by id:

Notes:
* If the User must exist: just use `find` instead of `find_by_id`
* Why do you have the `includes` in the first place? This will most like not help as you are selecting a single `User` I don't see why this would get you any benefit.